# alert() in DIV's onclick is not displayed after click

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have two rectangles with some text inside. I would like to display a different alert when I click on each one, but code below doesn't work (alert is not displayed). Any ideas? Thanks

```
<div id="panel0" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="titleBox" id="rect0" onclick="alert('yeah1');"
        style="height: 85px; width: 85px;">Hello</div>
    <div class="titleBox" id="rect1" onclick="alert('yeah2');"
        style="height: 85px; width: 85px;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Cyx2n/

Comment: @user411103 Your code is working for me too...

Comment: There's no problem with this code

Comment: is JS enabled on your machine/browser?

Comment: The same, may be there is other elements on your page?

Comment: Is the div absolutely positioned, and which browser is this happening in? I read in another post that IE before 8 requires background-color on absolutely positioned divs to capture clicks or the click falls through to the element behind.

Comment: @DavidMårtensson you should probably provide a reference / citation to that statement...

Comment: Thanks. At the same time I am controlling onclick event from GWT to trigger a different action. Could this be the cause?

Comment: The post was on another forum and I know from earlier that posting competing forum links is not really appreciated by every one :P.

Comment: @DavidMårtensson Why?! ...user411103: Yes, for sure.

Comment: Thank you lorenzo-s. @DavidMartensson: I didn't post this anywhere else. If you have a link to that previous post, please, provide a link. Thanks

Comment: The post I was referring to, about background-color. That post was on another forum and the last time I linked to another such site I got scowled for promoting a competitor. In this case, since the other post actually do not contain any more relevant information I just stated one possible solution. Thats also why I posted as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<div id="rect0" onclick="alert('yeah1');" style="height: 85px; width: 85px; background-color: #ff0000;">
     Hello
</div>
```